# Checking status of security panel remember option in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible to acquire status of Remember option in flash security panel for camera using AS3? It would be nice to have a function where it returns 1 if remember option is checked, 0 when it is unchecked and -1 if the remember option is not available due to browser/client settings.

Comment: there is a function  if you write it, use a variable to hold the information

Comment: No, it isn't possible. The best you can do is check the muted property when you first get the camera, to check if the value has already been remembered. Flash does not provide a handle for checking the setting directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use cookies in flash to store this varaible. So, why not use it
.

Example:

```
var mySharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("republicofcode");
mySharedObject.data.firstName = "John";
mySharedObject.data.lastName = "Doe";
mySharedObject.flush();
trace(mySharedObject.data.firstName);
trace(mySharedObject.data.lastName);
```

[for more info about my shared object see the link](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sharedobject/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question is more about acquiring the variable rather than storing it. But you have a point there and it trigged a question in my mind. The question is: can we extract webcam settings by reading cookies generated by flash movie? I understand flash uses cookies to store webcam settings in. It might be possible to read this cookie in flash movie and extract necessary info including "remember option" out of it.